# Полная копия таблицы sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Кроме очевидных способов

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM old_tbl;
```

Есть ли способ полного дублирование таблицы со всеми элементами вроде индексов или триггеров?

Comment: Экспорт `->` Импорт

Comment: Речь про SQL Server 2012

Comment: Гм... а зачем ЕЩЁ способ, если и этот выполняет требуемые функции?

Comment: Этот копирует только шапку и данные, а не все элементы таблицы вроде индексов и триггеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [SSMS: How to: Generate a Script (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx)

или "кастомной" процедурой [`sp_GetDDL`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/SQL+Server+2005/67515/) (исходник процедуры по ссылке...):

```
exec sp_GetDDL YourTableName
-- or

exec sp_GetDDL 'schemaname.tablename'

-- or

exec sp_GetDDL [schemaname].[tablename]
```

Comment: Эм. У меня нет такой хранимки sp_GetDDL. SQL Server 2012

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов У вас её и не должно быть, она у `dbo`.

Comment: @0xdb Ни exec sp_GetDDL YourTableName,
ни exec dbo.sp_GetDDL YourTableName не выполняются. 
"Could not find stored procedure".

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов, это __не__ встроенная процедура - я добавил информацию в ответ...

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо большое! Хотя, остался вопрос. Копирует не один в один.  Почему-то изменились значки индексов. Старые - в виде дерево объектов (один вверху, три внизу), а новые - в виде ключиков. Странно это -.- Зато скопировались все статистики - уже хорошо.

Comment: @MaxU А, нет. Не все статистики скопировал, только первую. Другие, видно, чем-то отличаются -.-